# How can I access a variable from another file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say that I have two files that are in separate directories:

```
/folder1/first.js

/folder1/folder2/second.js
```

`first.js` contains a variable called `newName`. Would it be possible to access it in `second.js`? (and how)?

EDIT: The HTML file is located in the same directory as `first.js`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use export function in the first.js file and use require in second.js to access that variable.

For example
If you have var named first in first .js.

```
const first = {
name: 'dharmik',
age: '21'
}
```

Export it like this:

`export { first };`

And then import in second.js like this:

`import { first } from './first.js'`

And then you can use the variable in second.js.

`console.log(first.name);`
//dharmik

Comment: I have tried using this, but as I have said in another post, using this method gives me an error. When I run my code in npm, it says that the `{` in `import { variable }` is an unexpected token.

Comment: Yes, [here is the code from `second.js`](https://pastebin.com/paAmy39R). @Dharmiksoni

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are just linking static HTML files with `<script>` tags, then they will share their global scope. In other words: yes, `second.js` will be able to access the top-level variables from `first.js`, assuming they were liked in that order. Directories have no bearing on the behavior.

Comment: When I link to both files, npm still says that `variable` is not defined.

Comment: What does npm have to do with this? What does your build process look like?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to add more code to [this project](https://github.com/mooradal/youtubeDownloader) on Github. In order to run the code, I have to type in `npm run dev` in the directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)/[`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) syntax.

In `first.js`:

```
let newName = "New Name";
export { newName };
```

In `second.js`:

```
import { newName } from "./../first.js";
```

Comment: Using this method gives me an error. When I run my code in npm, it says that the `{` in `import { variable }` is an unexpected token.

Comment: Oh, you're using NPM/Node? Use `require` instead.

Comment: so do I replace `import` with `require`, or do I type more?

Comment: in your consumer file like this; `const variableName = require('./sourceFile');`

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot assign to 'newName' because it is an import, even if you use `let`

Answer (score -1):

Technically yes this is possible, if you are going to access it from "second.js"

```
<script src="../first.js">
//code here that uses the global variable from first.js
</script>
```

The .. allows for file directory traversal, by going up 1 directory.