# django cannot export and import javascript variables in static files

Tags: javascript, django, django-staticfiles

I have static files in django call it A.js and B.js

in `A.js` I have for example for constant like

```
const variable = "Hello, World"
export {variable}
```

in `B.js` I have:

```
import {variable} from './A.js'
```

Kindly note that both files are in the static files directory of django project.

My question is how am I going to import successfully the variable so that it checks into variable and use them in the template without getting exceptions

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' and the whole JS does not work

I also needed to declare them as modules inside the template

```
 <script src='{% static "js/A.js" %}' type="module" ></script>
 <script src='{% static "js/B.js" %}' type="module" ></script>
```

either ways not working. I have previously used `export default` approach , still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys I found that django does not require webpacks import or export statement in order to access javascript variables,
Remember the `**

> python manage.py collectstatic

**` ,
it does the job of managing or you can also say bundling your django static files into a single file

In ruby on rails , there is an application.js or application.css, which is a root of all the other javascripts or css file within the assets folder of the rails framework

In a similar way, django does not specify a single file but its designed to automatically make all the files in a static folder visible to each other

thus without any import statement or export statement
I can easily call the variable in B.js which is defined in A.js

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
export default variable
```

instead of

```
export {variable}
```

Comment: tried that not working

Comment: Check this out, it might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313314/django-how-to-include-javascript-in-template

Comment: thats not the correct answer, this is about making javascript .js files communicate with each other not just loading static files into the template, import and exports statement cause issues and reference error, that  is what the question about

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411810/how-can-i-access-a-variable-from-another-file-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry mate, but django static files is not just like normal javascript and html